# Representations of the symmetric group with image in a given subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_m$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements. The irreducible representations of $S_n$ are parametrised by partitions $\lambda$ of $n$ and are defined already over the integers $\mathbb Z$.
Let $\rho^\lambda: S_n \to \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb Z)$ be such an irreducible representation.
I am curious whether there is a way to characterise when the image of $\rho^{\lambda}$ lies in a proper subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_m$, i.e. $$\rho^\lambda: S_n \to G(\mathbb Z) \subset \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb Z),$$
where $G$ is some (algebraic) group with an embedding into $\operatorname{GL}_m$, for example the symplectic group $\operatorname{Sp}_{2k}$, when $2k = m$. Ideally, such a characterisation would be given in terms of partitions and Young tableaux. I'd be happy to consider $\mathbb Q$-points instead of $\mathbb Z$-points, but don't really want to assume that my base is an algebraically closed field.

I'd be grateful for any leads.

Comment: My guess would be that a rep of $S_n$ preserves a symplectic form iff every irrep occurs with even multiplicity.

Comment: This was also posted on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798489/representations-of-the-symmetric-group-with-image-in-a-given-subgroup-of-opera

Answer (score 5):

Allow me to work over $\mathbb Q$ and study if $G = Sp_{2k}$ or $O_m$. Then a representation always carries an invariant orthogonal form, and (as YCor says in the comments) carries an invariant symplectic form if and only if each irreducible representation appears with even multiplicity.

Every irreducible representation of $S_n$ carries an invariant orthogonal form. (For example, Young constructed representation matrices which are orthogonal with respect to the dot product. [EDIT: knowing nothing about the symmetric group, we can also just average a positive-definite orthogonal form to obtain an invariant one.]) Now let $V$ be a representation of $S_n$ with an invariant symplectic form $\omega$. Since the complex irreducible representations of $S_n$ are defined over $\mathbb Q$, we have a decomposition

$$ V = \bigoplus_\lambda V_\lambda \otimes \mathrm{Hom}_{S_n}(V_\lambda,V),$$
where $V_\lambda$ is the Specht module associated to $V$. Taking the tensor product of the orthogonal form on $V_\lambda^*$ and $\omega$ on $V$ gives a symplectic form on $\mathrm{Hom}_{S_n}(V_\lambda, V)$. Thus, the multiplicity of $V_\lambda$ in $V$ is even for all $\lambda$. Conversely, if all multiplicies are even, specifying symplectic forms on $\mathrm{Hom}_{S_n}(V_\lambda,V)$ for all $V$ defines an invariant symplectic form via tensor products and direct sums on $V$.

Comment: Young's construction involves quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, so it's not quite "over $\mathbb{Q}$".

Comment: @DimaPasechnik good point. Using absolute irreducibility it can still be concluded that there are invariant orthogonal forms over $\mathbb Q$. I don't know how to describe which bilinear forms arise this way from the symmetric group.

Comment: Finding invariant nondegenerate symmetric forms on Specht modules is easy: Find one on $\mathbb{Q}\left[S_n\right]$ (the obvious one, which makes the standard basis orthogonal), then argue that it is positive-definite and restricts to every subrepresentation.

Comment: just take $\sum_{g\in S_n}\rho(g)\rho(g)^\top$ - it's a positive definite $\rho(S_n)$- invariant form, for any real representation $\rho$. So you don't even need $\mathbb{Q}$, as $\mathbb{Z}$ would suffice, no?

Comment: Yes, you can construct these invariant forms without using Young's construction. It still seems interesting to me to describe what class the invariant orthogonal form on $V_\lambda$ is in the Witt group of $\mathbb Q$, for example.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger Thank you very much! I'm also interested in cases where $G = \operatorname{Res}_{K/\mathbb Q}(H)$ for $K$ a number field and $H$ an algebraic group over $K$. Is there anything one can say in that case, at least, say, for $H = \operatorname{GL}_k$?

Comment: @bsbb4 A homomorphism $S_n \to GL_{n [K:\mathbb Q]}(\mathbb Q)$ lands in $\mathrm{Res}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\mathbb Q) = GL_n(K)$ if and only if the $\mathbb Q$-representation comes as restriction of scalars from a $K$-representation. This can be manufactured if and only if all the multiplicities are divisible by $[K:\mathbb Q]$ (so that $\mathrm{Hom}_{S_n}(V_\lambda ,V)$ can be given the structure of a $K$-vector space)

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger Thank you! Do you have any idea how to proceed for a general reductive group $G$?

Comment: @bsbb4 as far as I know, there is not a good theory explaining homomorphisms $\Gamma \to G(\mathbb C)$ for general reductive $G$. For types $B,C,D$ we have the Frobenius-Schur theory which lies in the background of my answer. You can generalize this to figure out whether a 7-dimensional complex representation lands inside $G_2(\mathbb C) \subseteq GL_7(\mathbb C)$. For types $E,F$ I have no idea.